# Making Math.random() more random?

Tags: javascript, random

I am slowly working my way through JavaScript and have run into an issue with Math.random().
I read on MDN that Math.random() is always seeded with the current Date - and I "believe" what is happening is that my two Math.random() calls are happening so quickly that they are returning basically the same value.  Here is the code, this is the beginnings of a card game.

```
var cards = new Array(null);
cards[0] = new Array("Ace of Spades","ace","A","spades","black");
cards[1] = new Array("Two of Spades","two","2","spades","black");
cards[2] = new Array("Three of Spades","three","3","spades","black");
// you get the idea ... full code on the JSFiddle below
cards[51] = new Array("King of Hearts","king","K","hearts","red");

// initialize variables
var cardsInHand = 5;

// variables to make the card drawing decrement work without touching original array
var restOfDeck = new Array(null);
restOfDeck = cards;

// initialize hands as a doubly-nested Arrays
var player1Hand = new Array(null);
var player2Hand = new Array(null);

// function to randomly "draw" the cards, decrementing the deck each time

for (var k = 0; k < cardsInHand; k++) {
        player1Hand[k] = restOfDeck[(Math.floor(Math.random() * restOfDeck.length))];
        restOfDeck.splice(restOfDeck.indexOf(player1Hand[k]), 1);
        console.log((k + 1) + ' cards to Player 1');
        player2Hand[k] = restOfDeck[(Math.floor(Math.random() * restOfDeck.length))];
        restOfDeck.splice(restOfDeck.indexOf(player2Hand[k]), 1);
        console.log((k + 1) + ' cards to Player 2');
    }

// display hand
document.write('Player 1\'s Hand\: <br />');
for (var i = 0; i < cardsInHand; i++) {
   document.write(player1Hand[i][0] + "<br />");
}
document.write('<br /><br />Player 2\'s Hand\: <br />');
for (var j = 0; j < cardsInHand; j++) {
    document.write(player2Hand[j][0] + "<br />");
}
```

What is happening that among the 10 cards "dealt", there are always two cards "in order" (Two  of Hearts, then Three of Hearts).  Always.  I believe it has something to do with the two Math.random() calls in the draw/decrement function, but I am not sure how to rework.  Thanks in advance!

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bjVCL/

Comment: Math.random is only seeded **once** for your application.

Comment: I'm not seeing it. The jsfiddle deals (seemingly) random cards.

Comment: Same as Juhana, I get a random selection. (Google Chrome)

Comment: Thanks for looking! But I am noticing that if you look closely at the 10 cards dealt, you can always find two cards "in order" - they may not be next to each other, but they will be there.  @dystroy's answer makes the most sense.  But how do I get a more "random" draw each time then?  and THANKS! again.

Comment: *you can always find two cards "in order"* : our brain easily see patterns in the random.

Comment: Are you saying they're always of the same suit as well, or just of adjacent value?  If the latter, this may just be simple statistics at work.

Comment: @broofa Thanks for looking!  Adjacent value.  Nine of Diamonds as the 3rd card in Player 1's hand, then Ten of Diamonds as the 4th cards in Player 2's hand, for example.

Comment: For any one card, the odds of finding one of its "neighbors" in a random selection of 9 other cards is about 30%. So the odds of finding at least one such collision in a set of 10 randomly chosen cards is about 97%. It would be odd _not_ to see that.

Comment: Okay, whew! THANKS. Glad to know I am not going too crazy. Thank you all again for looking.  Any comments on the code itself?

Comment: For other comments you might want to take it to [codereview.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just simple probability at work.  The only time you *won't* see adjacent pairs is if the card values are distributed such that ...

- 1st card - can be any value
- 2nd card - must be one of 11 values not adjacent to previous card (11:13 odds)
- 3rd card - must be one of 9 values not adjacent to previous two
- 4th card - must be one of 7 values not adjacent to previous three
- 5th card - must be one of 5 values not adjacent to previous four

Thus, the odds of getting a hand with **no** adjacent values is (13/13) * (11 * 13) * (9 * 13) * (7 / 13) * (5 / 13) = a paltry **12%**

(Note: 'my stastics is a little rusty so I may not have this quite right, but it's close enough to give a sense of the effect you're seeing.)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the Ecmascript6 spec does not address the quality of the random() function supplied by JS, but in practical terms it will typically use a well-known PRNG algorithm like a Mersenne Twister that produces numbers with well-known randomness qualities.  And be seeded from a variety of things like current time, timing of input events (key strokes, mouse movement), as well as CPU-supplied random values (e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RdRand)